# Is $\mu'$ countably additive when it is defined over an algebra of sets?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal A\subset 2^X$ an algebra of sets, $\mu$ pre-measure on $\mathcal A$. Given $B\subset X$, define $\mu'(B) = \inf\{\mu(A): B\subset A, A\in \mathcal A\}$. Is $\mu'$ countably subadditive?

I think the answer is no, altough I haven't found a counter-example yet. I tried to prove it in the following way: given $(B_n)$ sequence of subsets of $X$ and $\epsilon>0$, for each $n\in \mathbb N$ exists $A_n\subset \mathcal A$ such that $\mu(A_n) < \mu'(B_n)+\epsilon/2^n.$ We also note that if $C\subset D$ for subsets of $X$, it follows that $\mu'(C)\leq \mu'(D)$. So, since $\bigcup B_n \subset \bigcup A_n$, it follows that $\mu'(\bigcup B_n) \leq \mu'(\bigcup A_n)$. Since $\mathcal A$ is only an *algebra*, it is not true that $\bigcup A_n \in \mathcal A$, so I cannot proceeed with the argument here to state that $\mu'(\bigcup A_n) = \mu(\bigcup A_n) = \sum \mu(A_n) < \sum \mu'(B_n) + \epsilon$ and finish the proof.

So I *believe* that it is false. Any one can help me find a good counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = [0,1)$, let $\mathcal A$ be the set of finite disjoint unions of half-open intervals
$$
E = [a_1,b_1)\cup [a_2,b_2)\cup [a_n,b_n),\quad 0 \le a_1 <b_1 < a_2 <b_2 < \cdots < a_n < b_n \le 1,
$$
and let $\mu$ be the "length"
$$
\mu(E) = \sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k) 
$$
Then $\mu'$ should be the Jordan outer measure, which is not countably additive.

In particular, use this example:  If $B = (0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$ then $\mu'(B) = 1$.  But also $\mu'(\{x\}) = 0$ for any singleton.  Countable subadditivity fails.